# Get uncertainties of predicted values after linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, data-fitting

I perform a multiple linear regression:

```
dependent <- c(1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 8)
independent_a <- c(1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4)
independent_b <- c(0, 3, 2, 5, 9, 8)

model <- lm(dependent ~ independent_a + independent_b)
summary(model)
```

The predicted data are shown upon `fitted(model)`. How can I get the uncertainty of these values?

I am aware that I can calculate them applying error propagation from the uncertainties of the intercept and the coefficients that are shown with `summary(model)`. However, this calculation would assume uncorrelated contributions to the uncertainty whereas the multiple linear regression would suggest correlated contributions.

Comment: In fact, you cannot simply propagate the coefficients uncertainties because of the data covariance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the fitted values and their confidence interval.

```
predict(model, interval = "confidence")
#>        fit        lwr      upr
#> 1 1.048319 -1.4691124 3.565751
#> 2 3.199580  1.3321255 5.067034
#> 3 2.115546  0.2737039 3.957389
#> 4 3.716387  0.6079219 6.824851
#> 5 7.226891  4.8327685 9.621013
#> 6 6.693277  4.3901686 8.996386
```

More info: `?predict.lm`